# Select rows with same id but all null value in some another column and group by same id

Tags: mysql

I want to get only rows having a value NULL for a particular username column.

- If all rows have some values other than null
- or one of the row have some value other than null

then it should be ignored in output.

But, If all rows for same username with null value should be consider in output.

Below is example sample and output. How it can be done using sql query?

```
+----------+------------+
| username | id_group   |
+----------+------------+
| A        |    5       |
| A        |    7       |
| A        |    8       |
| B        |    12      |
| B        |   null     |
| C        |   null     |
| C        |    5       |
| D        |   null     |
| D        |   null     |
+----------+------------+
```

output

```
+----------+------------+
| username | id_group   |
+----------+------------+
| D        |   null     |
+----------+------------+
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9bb3a18/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one should be ok, you need to group all of your data and filter every group. This is what I did with the `HAVING` clause :

```
SELECT username, MAX(id_group) AS id_group
FROM T
GROUP BY username
HAVING MAX(id_group) IS NULL
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5297d230d7821af94beec1774861fcd1)

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9bb3a18/1)

Comment: The `MAX()` in the SELECT clause is unnecessary because it is guaranteed to be `NULL` due to the HAVING logic.

Comment: There is a `GROUP BY`, how can i do without the `MAX()` ?

Comment: The `MAX()` in the `HAVING` clause is necesary.  The call in the `SELECT` is not.  The column can safely be removed from the result set or hardcoded as `NULL AS id_group` ...I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Query with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT username 
FROM `table` t1 
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT username 
        FROM `table` t2 
        WHERE t2.username = t1.username AND t2.id_group IS NOT NULL
    )
```

Comment: I don't like this one from you.  Better to group by.

Comment: `GROUP BY` requires selecting and checking all records in a table, while `exists` will stop when finds/not finds a required row.

Comment: This returns both null roles from Not Exists,  Plus there is only really 1 table.  So add `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY username` and change `t2` to `t1 as t2`  see [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wLW48UXke14wWujLYrbXvC/2)